# How to create index to improve performance of an aggregate function that creates a table in oracle

Tags: oracle, optimization, aggregate, plsql, oracle-apex

I am creating an Oracle ORDS API using APEX_JSON. I recently started using bind variables instead of string concatenation using `||`. I am trying to use an `in` clause in my `where` condition.

The problems begin here. The field I need to have on the left side of `in` is a `number` and the parameter to my stored procedure needs to be `varchar2` as it is a comma seperated list of numbers.

**Example (edited for brevity)**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_CATEGORYPRODS (
    PCATEGORYID IN NUMBER,
    COMMASEPPRODUCTIDS IN VARCHAR2
) AS

l_cursor               SYS_REFCURSOR;
v_stmt_str             STRING(5000);
v_name                 NUMBER; --PRODUCT.NAME%TYPE;
v_displayorder         NUMBER; --PRODUCTCATEGORY%TYPE;
BEGIN
 v_stmt_str := 'SELECT 
    P.NAME, 
    PC.DISPLAYORDER
FROM 
    PRODUCT P
INNER JOIN
    PRODUCTCATEGORY PC
ON P.PRODUCTID = PC.PRODUCTID
WHERE 
   PC.CATEGORYID := :CATEGORYID
AND
   (P.PRODUCTID IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(STRING_TO_TABLE_NUM(:COMMASEPPRODUCTIDS))) -- PREVIOUSLY WHERE || OCCURRED
        OR (:COMMASEPPRODUCTIDS IS NULL))';

s_counter := 0;

OPEN l_cursor FOR v_stmt_str
        USING pcategoryid, commasepproductids, commasepproductids;

FETCH l_cursor INTO
    v_productid,
    v_displayorder;

APEX_JSON.OPEN_ARRAY;
LOOP
    EXIT WHEN l_cursor%notfound;
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('ProductID', v_productid);
    apex_json.write('DisplayOrder', v_displayorder);
    apex_json.close_object;
END LOOP;
apex_json.close_all;

END GET_CATEGORYPRODS;
```

**Sample of parameters**
`'97187,142555,142568,48418,43957,44060,45160,45171,333889,333898'`

To handle this problem, I created an aggregate function that takes in a string, splits on the commas, and pipes the row to a custom type.

**Custom Type**

```
create or replace type tab_number is table of number;
```

**Aggregate Function**

```
create or replace FUNCTION string_to_table_num (
    p VARCHAR2
)

   RETURN tab_number
   PIPELINED IS
BEGIN
   FOR cc IN (SELECT rtrim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]*,', 1, level), ',') res
                FROM (SELECT p || ',' str FROM dual)
              CONNECT BY level <= length(str) 
                                  - length(replace(str, ',', ''))) LOOP
      PIPE ROW(lower(cc.res));
   END LOOP;
    
END;
```

The query slowed down significantly. I figured some optimization was needed but I had never done any sort of optimization before. After some research, I found `EXPLAIN PLAN` and ran it on the orginal query. I couldn't get a good answer because of the bind variables, so I decided to run it on the aggregate function.

**EXPLAIN PLAN QUERIES**

```
explain plan for select * from TABLE(string_to_table_num('97187,142555,142568,48418,43957,44060,45160,45171,333889,333898'));

SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
```

When I ran `EXPLAIN PLAN` for the aggregate function the results were:

```
Plan hash value: 127161297
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                     |  8168 | 16336 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| STRING_TO_TABLE_NUM |  8168 | 16336 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As I stated before, I am a noob to analyzing and optimizing queries, but 8168 Rows and 16336 bytes seems to be a lot for such a simple function. I looked into it, and found that the problem may be the lack of indexing of the pipelined table. I tried to add an index to the type `tab_number` but it turned it into a PL/SQL object that needed to be declared in a query, not a function.

I am pretty lost with this one. If you have any suggestions for any of the scenarios I mentioned, I am all ears. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
After following the steps in Balazs's answer below, I ran `EXPLAIN PLAN` for both the aggregate function and the `select` from my procedure.

**Aggregate Function**

```
Plan hash value: 229973419
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |            |  8168 | 16336 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| F_CONVERT2 |  8168 | 16336 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Select Function**

```
Plan hash value: 1690769838
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name                                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                                     |     6 |  2790 |   972   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                                 |                                     |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER                    |                                     |    65 | 30225 |   972   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER                   |                                     |    65 | 27950 |   842   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                        |                                     |    65 | 27365 |   777   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| PRODUCTCATEGORY                     |    65 |   845 |   712   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       INDEX SKIP SCAN                   | SYS_C0012982                        |    65 |       |   709   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | PRODUCTNEW                          |     1 |   408 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | SYS_C0013161                        |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | SYS_C0012993                        |     1 |     9 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | IDX_URLMAPPER_PRODUCTID_FRIENDLYURL |     1 |    35 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |   COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH     | F_CONVERT2                          |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter(:COMMASEPPRODUCTIDS IS NULL OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM TABLE() "KOKBF$0" WHERE VALUE(KOKBF$)=:B1))
   6 - access("pc"."CATEGORYID"=TO_NUMBER(:PCATEGORYID))
       filter("pc"."CATEGORYID"=TO_NUMBER(:PCATEGORYID))
   7 - filter("p"."PUBLISHED"=1 AND "p"."DELETED"=0)
   8 - access("p"."PRODUCTID"="pc"."PRODUCTID")
   9 - access("p"."PRODUCTID"="pm"."PRODUCTID"(+))
  10 - access("p"."PRODUCTID"="um"."PRODUCTID"(+))
  11 - filter(VALUE(KOKBF$)=:B1)
```

Do these numbers seem to be within a reasonable range?

**EDIT 2**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_CATEGORYPRODS2 
(
  COMMASEPPRODUCTIDS IN VARCHAR2 
, COMMASEPPRODUCTSKUS IN VARCHAR2 
, PCATEGORYID IN NUMBER 
, SORTBY IN VARCHAR2 
)

....

IF sortby IS NULL OR sortby = 'null' OR sortby = '' THEN
        v_sortby := '"p".Discontinued, "pc".DisplayOrder ';
    ELSIF sortby = 'PriceAscending' THEN
        v_sortby := '"p".discontinued, "p".price ';
    ELSIF sortby = 'PriceDescending' THEN
        v_sortby := '"p".discontinued, "p".price DESC ';
    ELSIF sortby = 'Name' THEN
        v_sortby := '"p".discontinued, "p".name ';
    ELSE
        v_sortby := '"p".discontinued, "pc".displayorder ';
    END IF;
....
```

I was also using a bind variable to add this to the end of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
create or replace type tab_number is table of number;

create or replace FUNCTION string_to_table_num (p VARCHAR2) RETURN tab_number
   res tab_nubmer;
BEGIN

   select regexp_substr(p,'[^,]+', 1, level) 
   bulk collect into res
   from dual
   connect by regexp_substr(p, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;

   return res;
END;
```

and use it similar to this:

```
   ids tab_nubmer := string_to_table_num(COMMASEPPRODUCTIDS);

begin

   OPEN l_cursor FOR 
   SELECT 
      P.NAME, 
      PC.DISPLAYORDER
   FROM PRODUCT P
      INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATEGORY P ON P.PRODUCTID = PC.PRODUCTID
WHERE PC.CATEGORYID = CATEGORYID
  AND P.PRODUCTID MEMBER of ids;
```

You don't need dynamic SQL.

An `ORDER BY` can be done like this:

```
ORDER BY "p".discontinued,
   CASE sortby 
      WHEN 'PriceAscending' THEN "p".price
      WHEN 'PriceDescending' THEN "p".price DESC
      WHEN 'Name' THEN "p".name
      ELSE "pc".DisplayOrder -- includes 'null' or ''
   END
```

Comment: oh wow i like that a lot better than the function I was using. I appreciate the tip! If i were to want to sort on a dynamic value, would that be possible without dynamic SQL? Say if there was `SORTBY IN VARCHAR2` and it went through an `IF` loop. I'll put an example in my question.

Comment: The list of product ids can also be null, I took it out of the original question because I did not think it could be done without dynamic SQL. Is there a way to handle that without dynamic SQL?

Comment: @Josh, see my update

Comment: I tried it that way, but it did not like `"p".price DESC` for some reason. It said invalid expression. But regardless, that is a small piece of the puzzle that i can work out at a later date.

Comment: It actually gave me a `ORA-00905: missing keyword` and underlined `DESC` as where the error is occurring. Not an invalid expression error. My apologies.

Comment: I think then you have to use dynamic SQL

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. It is much appreciated. I got the query minus the order by working with your method. I removed the APEX_JSON.write calls as well and am now getting the data back quickly.

Answer (score 1):

8168 rows and 16336 bytes are just default values.

If you want more realistic values, you can use [ASSOCIATE STATISTICS](https://docs.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql&id=SQLRF01106).

Here is an example:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions

Without `ASSOCIATE STATISTICS`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_ptf (p_cardinality IN INTEGER DEFAULT 1)
  RETURN t_tf_tab PIPELINED AS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
    PIPE ROW (t_tf_row(i, 'Description for ' || i));
  END LOOP;

  RETURN;
END;
/

SET AUTOTRACE TRACE EXPLAIN

-- Return 10 rows.
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(get_tab_ptf(10));

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 822655197

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |             |  8168 | 16336 |     8   (0)| 00:02:19 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| GET_TAB_PTF |  8168 | 16336 |     8   (0)| 00:02:19 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SET AUTOTRACE OFF
```

With `ASSOCIATE STATISTICS`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_ptf_stats AS OBJECT (
  dummy INTEGER,
  
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIGetInterfaces (
    p_interfaces OUT SYS.ODCIObjectList
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIStatsTableFunction (
    p_function    IN  SYS.ODCIFuncInfo,
    p_stats       OUT SYS.ODCITabFuncStats,
    p_args        IN  SYS.ODCIArgDescList,
    p_cardinality IN INTEGER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_ptf_stats AS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIGetInterfaces (
    p_interfaces OUT SYS.ODCIObjectList
  ) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    p_interfaces := SYS.ODCIObjectList(
                      SYS.ODCIObject ('SYS', 'ODCISTATS2')
                    );
    RETURN ODCIConst.success;
  END ODCIGetInterfaces;

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIStatsTableFunction (
                    p_function    IN  SYS.ODCIFuncInfo,
                    p_stats       OUT SYS.ODCITabFuncStats,
                    p_args        IN  SYS.ODCIArgDescList,
                    p_cardinality IN INTEGER
                  ) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    p_stats := SYS.ODCITabFuncStats(NULL);
    p_stats.num_rows := p_cardinality;
    RETURN ODCIConst.success;
  END ODCIStatsTableFunction;
END;
/

ASSOCIATE STATISTICS WITH FUNCTIONS get_tab_ptf USING t_ptf_stats;
```

And the result:

```
SET AUTOTRACE TRACE EXPLAIN

SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(get_tab_ptf(p_cardinality => 10));

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 822655197

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |             |    10 |    20 |     8   (0)| 00:02:19 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| GET_TAB_PTF |    10 |    20 |     8   (0)| 00:02:19 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(get_tab_ptf(p_cardinality => 10000));

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 822655197

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |             | 10000 | 20000 |     8   (0)| 00:02:19 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| GET_TAB_PTF | 10000 | 20000 |     8   (0)| 00:02:19 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SET AUTOTRACE OFF
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. To use the associative statistics with my query, I would run `ASSOCIATE STATISTICS WITH FUNCTIONS string_to_table_num USING t_ptf_stats;` and then just run the query while `AUTOTRACE` is set to `TRACE`?

Comment: @Josh `AUTOTRACE` is used in the above example only for demonstration purpose, to show the execution plan. You can just run your query and use `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);` to display the execution plan of the last statement.

Comment: I edited my question to include the results from the `EXPLAIN PLAN` with the associate statistics. Do they seem to be within an acceptable range?